# Why does rust allow us to store mutablre referneces to a immutable variable?

Tags: rust, immutability, borrow-checker, ownership

In rust, if we can store mutable reference to a mutable variable, like so:

```rs
fn main() {
    let mut str: String = String::new(); // a mutable string 
    let ref1 = &mut str; // storing a mutable reference to an immutable variable
    //   ^      ^ but the reference is mutable
    //   ^ immutable variable
    ref1.push_str(" Wait, ref1 was not marked mutable");
    //     ^ though we marked 'ref1' as immutable, we can mutate its value
    println!("{ref1}");
}
```

Why does `rust` allow it? Shouldn't a mutable reference be stored in a mutable variable?